# What are the implications of offering a public voting system (no sign-in required)?

Tags: voting

I am wondering what are the technical hurdles involved with offering a voting system (or say ratings) without requiring the user to sign in. I know there are issues with robots, voting a bunch - but what if you keep the users IP address? Do proxies become an issue?

I'd like to build a public voting system that is still reliable.. is that possible right now?

**EDIT**
The stakes are moderately high for correctness, that is human-verification, and one-vote-per-user. A full-fledged login will ask too much of the user given his role (voter)

Also, if this is "impossible" to accomplish, how can you detect vote fraud after the fact? Could wikipedia's model work here?

Thanks,
Matt Mueller

Comment: It all depends of the incentive for someone to rig your system. It can easily be made "reliable" if opponents' interest in breaking it is $100, less easily if opponents' interest in breaking it is $100k. Even CAPCHA systems have been broken by determined groups (who had nothing better to do with their time): http://musicmachinery.com/2009/04/27/moot-wins-time-inc-loses/

Comment: Wow.. haha. Poor Time.. I'm editing my post to add additional information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you said, you'll need to handle robot behavior.

If you log an IP address, you'll have problems with corporate users which usually stay behind a proxy, so everyone seems to have same IP.

Maybe you should to display some CAPTCHA image to validate human votes. Can't be that hard for users, since it's suppose to vote only once.

**EDIT**: How to enforce one vote per user?

You can:

- Ask for a valid email and send a link to vote
- To log your user in and let it vote
- Let user vote and save a cookie
- Let user vote and ban user IP

All this options have a weakness, so you'll never be sure.

To handle this problem "definitely", you'll probably need to bind their virtual identity with their *real* identity. This can be done by asking for personal information and keeping it. But that brings a whole new problem set.

Comment: Good idea on CAPTCHA! So now you know its not a bot.. how do you prevent the same user from voting a bunch of times then?

Comment: Cookies!

...I mean a cookie. Clearing it is enough work to avoid most repeated hand-voting.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. One thing... binding sounds like a login. This is the one thing I'm trying to avoid.. the goal is to make it as easy as possible to vote - I just want to keep it a legitimate system.

Comment: Also, Can't you just write a bash program to clear cookies and revote maybe? The stakes are moderately high.. unfortunately.

Comment: I tried to avoid login, just as you said on your question. But is hard, if not impossible, to guarantee unique votes without determining user identity

Comment: Yah.. I think I'm just going to do what a lot of sites do. When they go to vote - require them to sign in.

Comment: It's sad, but necessary; by definition, unique vote per user requires unique users. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, be sure the voting uses POST to prevent robots and pre-caching clients to cause a vote.

Restricting IP addresses will cause problems with dynamic IP ranges, proxies and people sharing a connection, so I wouldn't go this way.
Most of those systems remember that a user a voted using a cookie, but this can of course easily be tricked by deleting the cookie or just using a different browser.

Comment: Good call. What about sessions?

Comment: Sessions require a unique value to be send back to the server, either in a cookie or in the URL. Either way, it can be removed.